# Evitar el error #1442 de MySQL al Inserar y ejecutar un trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER `user_tel` AFTER INSERT ON `usuarios`
 FOR EACH ROW 
 TROW BEGIN

DECLARE TEL CHAR(14);
DECLARE ID INT;
SET TEL =  (SELECT telefono FROM usuarios ORDER BY idUsuario DESC LIMIT 1);
SET ID = (SELECT idUsuario FROM usuarios ORDER BY idUsuario DESC LIMIT 1);
BEGIN
UPDATE usuarios
SET telefono = Cast(Replace(Replace(Replace(Tel,'-',' '),'(',' '),')',' ') As CHAR)
WHERE idUsuario = ID;
END;
END;
```

Este codigo es para remplazar los parentesis y el guion en los telefonos

Ej.

(999) 999-9999
por
999 999 9999

pero al insertar en la tabla

me sale el siguiente error

> ## 1442 - Can't update table 'usuarios' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>
> function/trigger.

Me podrian ayudar por favor

Comment: Si el error es claro. Estas tratando de hacer un updae a una tabla en la cual todavia no terminaste de insertar algo. No se supone que toques los datos que acabas de agregar en la tabla, esos datos deberian venir sanos desde quien los mando.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: El trigger actualiza despues de que se inserta, deberia de funcionar, ya que lo he realizado de la misma manera en SQL server y funciona.

Comment: OK tenes razon. pero protesta que estas tratando de actualizar una tabla que estas usando. Tal vez, en mysql, la estrategia de la base de datos al hacer un update sea diferente y no te deja hacer select? deberias revisar eso...

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, seguire investigando.

Comment: La documentación es explícita en este aspecto: `A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.`, ver [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Restrictions for Stored Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-function-restrictions). Perdonar que la referencia sea en inglés.

Comment: Gracias ya lo había visto antes de leer tu respuesta, pero de todas maneras gracias.